# How to draw a custom menu on MFC SDI dynamically

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to draw a custom popup menu on MFC single-document interface (SDI) project.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d07e6whh.aspx), I found `The framework calls this member function for the owner of an owner-draw button control, combo-box control, list-box control, or menu when a visual aspect of the control or menu has changed.`

So I added the handle `OnDrawItem(int nIDCtl, LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)` and added some code inside this function, but I found that this callback didn't be called by the framework when I right click on the view, like this:
[image]

How to make a popup menu dynamically?

Here is how I get my pop up menu:

```
void Cdynamic_menu_sdiView::OnContextMenu(CWnd* /* pWnd */, CPoint point)
{
    if (IDR_MY_MENU == 0)
        return;
    CMenu dynamicMenu, proxyMenu;
    if (dynamicMenu.GetSafeHmenu())
        dynamicMenu.DestroyMenu();
    // Create a new popup menu.
    if (dynamicMenu.CreatePopupMenu() == FALSE)
        return;

    if (proxyMenu.LoadMenu(IDR_MY_MENU) == FALSE)
        return;

    int nSubMenu = 1;
    CMenu* pProxyMenu = proxyMenu.GetSubMenu(nSubMenu);

    build_dynamic_menu(m_map_menu_element_2, pProxyMenu, dynamicMenu, CString(""));
    //m_menu_on_draw = &dynamicMenu; // link up the dynamic menu to the on draw menu, so that we can print it on the screen

    CPoint ptCurPos; // current cursor position
    GetCursorPos(&ptCurPos);
    dynamicMenu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, ptCurPos.x, ptCurPos.y, AfxGetMainWnd(), NULL);
}
```

Inside the function `build_dynamic_menu()`, it is a depth first search function, I do `InsertMenu(i, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_POPUP | MF_OWNERDRAW, uSubMenuID, strLabel);` so that I can change the text of the popup menu dynamically.
Since it is too long to put the function here, I only state the idea.
I also want to change the text color and background color dynamically, so I am trying to find a way to draw the menu by code.

Where should I start? Is [owner drawn menus](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7073/How-to-create-owner-drawn-menus-Step-by-Step) approach good for me?

Comment: Is it an owner-draw menu? If not, that function won't be called.

Comment: Thanks, @immibis, I will try to look at this first `http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7073/How-to-create-owner-drawn-menus-Step-by-Step`

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with `OnDrawItem`. Show how you are loading the popup menu.

Comment: And if you just want to add normal menu items then owner-draw is ***not*** what you are looking for.